# Pulseaudio keeps getting killed in Oneiric

Tags: 11.10, pulseaudio

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric), my pulseaudio tends to crash a few times a day, if I'm listening to music on YouTube.  It restarts automatically (as long as I'm using a Unity session -- it doesn't auto-restart if I use GNOME, apparently), but forgets the volume setting (speaker icon shows 'Mute'), which is how I know it crashed.  Also I need to reload the browser tab with youtube to make it play sound again.

I'm trying to debug this.  When I use a GNOME Shell session instead of Unity, pulseaudio dies and doesn't autorestart.  I have to restart it manually in a terminal.  (Also, my volume icon disappears and volume keys stop reacting.  Even after I restart PA manually.)

This is how I noticed that PA wasn't just crashing -- it was getting killed by a signal (SIGKILL).

**EDIT**: evidence for this: `LANGUAGE=C pulseaudio -vv` dies with a message "Nutraukta (Killed)", which ignores my request (LANGUAGE=C) to use English, so I assume it comes from bash and not pulseaudio itself.  And $? is equal to 137, which is 128 (killed by a signal) + 9 (SIGKILL).

I haven't figured out a pattern yet.  This doesn't happen always -- sometimes I play maybe 10 songs on YouTube and then PA gets killed as I try to watch the 11th.  Sometimes it gets killed after a long period of inactivity.  Sometimes it gets killed on resume.

Any ideas how I might track who is killing my PA?  I intend to file a bug about this, once I figure out what is happening and which program is responsible.

**UPDATE**: people in #pulseaudio on irc.freenode.net say it could be a bug in the alsa driver that makes pulseaudio keep rewinding the stream, eating the CPU in a realtime thread, which then gets killed by the kernel for exceeding cputime limits.  I'm still trying to reproduce this with verbose pulseaudio debugging enabled.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**: I've reproduced the issue a few times, once under strace, once with pulseaudio -vvvv.  There's nothing suspicious (to me) in any of the logs just before the SIGKILL arrives.

Comment: Perhaps this question should instead be filed as a bug report? [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).