# Sound indicator + control disappeared in Shell

Tags: 11.10, sound, gnome

The sound indicator in the Gnome Shell panel sometimes disappears, I didn't notice any action from my side that may have triggered it. When I open the sound settings manually, I can't adjust anything either, however, the sound in general still works fine. Restarting X brings things back to normal.

Any idea how I can regain control over the sound settings short of restarting the entire system? I'm running 11.10 with Gnome-Shell 3.2.

Somebody asked the same question a couple of days ago, which was closed for being "too localized". I'm obviously not the only one affected so I can only guess that Gnome-Shell is too niche here. If so, please just close this one as well.

UPDATE: I just found that all details of my problem match the bug described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105593/pulseaudio-keeps-getting-killed-in-oneiric). Can somebody please mark my question a duplicate? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you still have pulseaudio installed. Otherwise, the sound indicator will not appear.

Comment: pulseaudio is installed. This isn't a general problem with my setup but occurs rather frequently after X has been running for while. Even then, sound is still there, just not adjustable, and restarting X fixes things.